# Using Three.js with Meteor

Tags: meteor, three.js

I am trying to load the basic rotating cube example from the three.js getting started guide in to a basic meteor app:
http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cube);

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

I have added this code into a template js manager file of a new meteor app and then call the render function on the render of my template:

  Template.hello.rendered = function() {
         if (!this._rendered) {
             this._rendered = true;
             render();
         }
     }

My template

<template name="hello">

    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    </head>
<body>
</body>

</template>
```

I have added three.js from atomosphere via:
mrt add three
and it loaded the package successfully into my app
However, when I start meteor I am getting an error that THREE is undefined.
I have tried moving three.js into the lib folder and that didn't work because I get an error that 'self' is undefined.  I think this should only load as a client library.  I have tried putting it with the client folder and below my manager file, but that didn't seem to work either and it seemed hacky.  It seems like meteorite installed packages should be loaded first, right?  WHy isn't this available from my template manager?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am new to both meteor and three.js so I think getting this basic demo working would really open my eyes.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I gave that a try without luck.  I am still getting an error that 'THREE is not defined'.  I tried initially in my original project with min.three.js package installed in that folder.  I also tried creating a new app without the three.js atmosphere package installed to make sure it wasn't causing a problem.  In both cases, I am getting an error that 'THREE is not defined'.  I can't understand why THREE should not be available to my template manager.

Answer (score 2):

Use the bower package and add three js through that.

https://atmospherejs.com/package/bower

I find that a lot of the wrapper packages on atmosphere fall out of date, so the bower package is a nice solution for this sort of thing.

Comment: It might be worth adding Meteor's typic behavior is to loads files that are nested in the lowest folder within your apps directory tree **first** 

i.e. any javascript files in `/client/compatibility/config/` would load before `/client/compatibility/`.

Answer (score 1):

The `THREE.js` library should go into `client/compatibility` folder. The package you were trying to use is probably deprecated.

**EDIT**

You can also try wrapping your `THREEJS` code with `Meteor.startup` to ensure the work is only performed after all `js` files are loaded. The Meteor's file loading order has always been a headake.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate the feedback!
I also tried Bower and got a reference error on a new project after installing threejs package via Bower after starting Meteor.  I am not sure what the issue is there.

However, I think I identified the problem with using three.js in the client folder.  THREE is defined with VAR so only has local file scope and was not available from my manager file.  There is a newer atmosphere package that has modified this to use a global scope:
https://atmospherejs.com/package/three.js

This package works.  I found that you can also use the newest min.three.js file directly in the client folder without installing a package if you add `window.THREE = THREE;` to the end of the file--giving the local `THREE` variable access to global scope.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that I had defined my 'var scene' and other three.js code as shown in my question outside of the if Meteor.isClient function.  Since my three.js code was within the client folder and inaccessible to the server, the server was throwing this error.

I hope someone finds my pitfalls helpful.  Meteor definitely requires *a slightly* new way of looking at a JS appilcation, but I think it will be really great.  I am excited to move past this seemingly simple issue that has been driving me crazy.